# Why can't / doesn't U-boot log messages for us to view later

Tags: mount, logs, boot-loader, u-boot, beagleboneblack

I have a problem whereby a remote BeagleBone device is taking hours to boot up. When it does, I don't see any problems in the kernel boot logs such as *journalctl -b* or *journalctl -b -1*

Without having physical access to the device over the serial interface, we can't see what is happening in the bootloader. Why is it that the U-Boot bootloader logs are not saved to somewhere on the flash memory or even RAM, or somewhere readable from when the kernel takes over? This would be extremely useful.

I understand that the file system is not mounted at that point, but surely there could be a solution? Or am I missing something that makes this procedure very difficult?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the net console as an output device to monitor the boot process. Cf. https://github.com/trini/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.NetConsole.

Since v2020.07 U-Boot can emit syslog messages via UDP depending on configuration (CONFIG_LOG_SYSLOG=y). You will need a syslog server to record the messages.